# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. while using flask and python to run app.py file?

Tags: python, flask, chatterbot

I am trying to run a chatbot application in python with flask but getting error as "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found" . I have been facing this issue for a long time but found no solution (I get this error even when i try importing Keras and tensorflow packages ,though these packages were successfully installed on my system.

Comment: is it possible that the packages were installed under a different flavor of python?  Like python 2.7 vs 3.7?

Comment: Well i have python 3.6 version installed on my system and later i installed Anaconda python 3.7 version.

Comment: look in the site-packages dir.  `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages` `/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages`.

Comment: Thanks Shremouse, but can you please explain what do i look in the site packages

Comment: Are you running under Windows or LINUX?